# Option pricing under distribution assumption

Tags: option-pricing, finance-mathematics, distribution

For simplicity assume zero interest rates in the following.

Given the price of a (European) put option with strike K and maturity T at time point t. $P_t(K, T)$ for a given underlying S with values $S_t$ at time point t.

Assuming you are currently at timepoint $t_0$. The return of S over the lifespan of the option is given by $r_T=\frac{S_T-S_0}{S_0}$.

Assuming that $r_t \sim f$. For some density $f$. Is the risk-neutral price of the option equal to the expected value of the option (if it exists, i.e. is finite)? So is this true? If not, why not?

$$P_{t_0}(K, T) = \mathbb{E}(P_T(K,T)=\int_{0}^{K} K-S_T \: dP(S_T) = \int_{-1}^{\frac{K-S_0}{S_0}} K-(1+r_T)S_0\: dP(r_T) \\
= \int_{-1}^{\frac{K-S_0}{S_0}} (K-(1+x)S_0) \: f(x)\: dx$$

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing further literature, I have come to the conclusion that indeed this method gives the correct answer. This thought process can be used to derive BS-formula, given the (risk-neutral) density of the "results" of the underlying stochastic process.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Risk-neutral option pricing involves more than just taking an expectation. The core of it is to replicate a payoff by trading in assets. Under a certain numeraire these asset prices must be martingales so that we don't have arbitrage. Assuming $r_t\sim f$ for some density is far from meeting those requirements.

Comment: @KurtG. I think I know what you mean, but I want to double check and learn. 
My hypothesis is: The value of an option is only equal to the expected value (ignoring interest rates) if you are risk-indifferent (may be a better word than risk-neutral).
I don't really get the replication argument as this assumes that you can dynamically hedge options (doesn't work under certain conditions for density of $r_T$). I do not necessarily see the problem in assuming just a density, although I acknowledge that further "no-arbitrage" arguments have to be respected. Note: my model assumes only 1 timestep.

Comment: The title of your question starts with "Risk-neutral option pricing". Black, Scholes and Merton have shown that under the assumption of risk-neutrality of the probability measure the price of an option is the expected value of the payoff. For this they received a Nobel prize in economics. They used a replication argument to prove mathematically that this expectation must be the price. If you think that any expectation under a "risk-indifferent" measure is also the option price the bar for proving that hangs very very high.

Comment: We cannot just mechanically calculate expectations despite the fact that the entire finance industry is doing just that. :)

Comment: I thought about the problem a little bit more and already learned a lot, thank you. I think my problem is the definition of risk-neutral. In my case I assume that given an expected (value) payoff, I do not care about risk (no matter how you want to describe risk ;)). (So linear utility function). Then I should price derivatives based on their (discounted) expected value under real world probabilities, right?
In Black-Scholes reasoning there is no risk because of dynamic hedging/replication. This leads to a martingale measure etc. Is this correct?

Comment: I thought about it even more (Even though the question was meant to be just a small idea, it grabbed my attention :)). I think it is mathematically robust (by put-call parity) to assume that option payoff has to be evaluated at the same measure as the forward. If the forward is priced risk-neutral $\rightarrow$ the option is priced risk-neutral. I agree, that this is not necessarily the "real-world" density as assumed above, but I will think about it.